# Build docker ubuntu image by Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If command "docker run ubuntu bash" the container won't last.

but if I command "docker run -it ubuntu bash"
the container will make a pseudo-tty and keep this container alive.

my question is 
is there any way I can make a Dockerfile for building an image based on ubuntu/centos then I just need to command "docker run my-image" and 
the container will last.

apologize for my poor english, I don't know if my question is clear enough.
thanks for any response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to run containers:

- task containers - do one thing and then exit, like `docker run ubuntu ls /`
- interactive containers - open a connection to the container with `-it`, like `docker run -it ubuntu bash`
- background containers - keep a container running detached in the background with `-d`, like `docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 ping localhost`

Docker keeps the container running as long as there is an active process in the container. The first container exits when the `ls` command completes. The second container will exit when you exit the bash session. The third container will stay running as long as the `ping` process keeps running (note that `ping` has been removed from the recent Ubuntu images, which is why the example specifies 14.04).